# Closing browser in Intel XDK and return to app

Tags: javascript, html, intel-xdk

I'm building a small app with Intel XDK. I need to open and close external browser window. I use this code to open browser but I can't find a solution to close the browser window and return to app. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
<script>

function OpenPage(){

         intel.xdk.device.launchExternal("http://www.example.com");

     }    

</script>

<a onclick="OpenPage();">Open Page</a>
```

Comment: Check this link, friend: http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/how_to_close_the_browser_window_and_return_back_to_the_app_window_in_iphone_web_app

Comment: Thanks. Actually realised that basic Javascript back link does the trick for me.

Comment: Do not put a solution in a question. Instead, write it as an answer. Also, do not put the status "solved" in the question title. A question is solved via one or more answers.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for information. My 1st time here so some of the guide lines are still new to me.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was simpler I thought:

```
<a href="javascript:history.go(-1);">Go back</a>
```